# How to trigger a click event on li after the page has loaded in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, click

I am trying to trigger a click event once the whole page is loaded. I am using reactjs. So how can I do it?

**What I have already tried**

```
componentDidMount(){
 this.triggerClick()
}

triggerClick() {
  var v = document.getElementById("24");
  if(v) {
    v.click()
  }
}

render() {
  let articles = this.state.data.map((articleData, index) => {
     return (
            <li key={index} id={articleData.id}>{articleData.name}</li>
     )
  }
}
```

I tried this, though there was id with 24, still it couldnt trigger the click() event

Comment: What have you tired?

Comment: componentDidMount() from the page container. https://developmentarc.gitbooks.io/react-indepth/content/life_cycle/birth/post_mount_with_component_did_mount.html

Comment: @MateuszJ check the edit..I have updated what I have tried

Answer (score 0):

Just use onClick

```
class myComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(event) {
    // what you want to do
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <li>
        <ul onClick={this.handleClick}> My clickable member of a list
        </ul>
      </li>
    );
  }
}
```

This is the React way of handling events. You say you want to use the click() from html but I can't see why you want that approach instead :)

[Some references](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

Comment: thank you for the reply. But i want to use click() event that gets triggered automatically when the page is ready

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fire the event automatically on page load then you can do this:-
Inside componentDidMount life cycle hook you can target the li then run click() on it, you can use java script selector or refs for that. Personally I will prefer to avoid ref and trigger the event using java script class/id selectors.